# Connect-PnPOnline promt log in browser instead of using credentials

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, sharepoint-online

I want to connect to sharepoint tenant und use the following code:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -Scopes "Group.ReadWrite.All","User.Read.All","Directory.Read.All","Sites.Read.All" -Credentials $cred
```

But it opens a log in browser to put in the credentials instead of using the $cred. 
The reason for using -Scopes is that I want to use Get-PnPUnifiedGroup to get id of office 365 groups.

Has anybody an idea how to avoid log in screen and uses the cred?

When I remove -Scopes [...] everything works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed my issue with the following step:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId YOURAPPID -AppSecret YOURAPPSECRET -AADDomain YOURDOMAIN
```

Afterwards i  removed the -Scopes from Connect-PnPOnline to the SharePoint tenant and I can use Get-PnPUnifiedGroup.

So if someone gets the same error, maybe this answer will help to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround you may want to use, all you need to to is to connect using an azure app registration, rather than normal credentials. [Here is a short explanation](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/258458/65662)